# Map<String, Map<String, String>> - Select key of value using Stream

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have this Map:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> listMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to select all distinct `Keys` from `Map` which is value in main `Map`: `listMap.value.key`

```
List<String> distinct = listMap.entrySet().stream()
                                .map(e -> e.getValue()) //Map<String, String>
                                //Select key of value
                                .distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I don't know how to select `key` of `value` of `listMap`.

Comment: `.flatMap(e -> e.getValue().keySet().stream())`

Comment: If I'm not wrong what your goal is -> modify @Eran 's answer and put `.filter(listMap::containsKey)` just before the collect operator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `flatMap` in order to map all the keys of all the inner `Map`s into a single `Stream`:

```
List<String> distinct = 
    listMap.values() // Collection<Map<String,String>>
           .stream() // Stream<Map<String,String>>
           .flatMap(map -> map.keySet().stream()) // Stream<String>
           .distinct() // Stream<String>
           .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<String>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way of collecting these could be in a `Set` as:

```
Set<String> distinct = new LinkedHashSet<>(); // for a predictable order
listMap.values().forEach(e -> distinct.addAll(e.keySet()));
```

Comment: According to the OP, the source is a `HashMap`, so there’s no point in trying to retain an order.